# dynamiclinkmediaserver folder in ~/Documents from Lightroom

Tags: adobe-lightroom

Every time I view a video in Lightroom 4, it creates an empty folder in ~/Documents called "Adobe" with the folder "dynamiclinkmediaserver" inside. This is very annoying because I would like to keep my Documents rid of useless folders. Is there any way to prevent this folder from being created? Whenever I delete it, the folder comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has annoyed me for a while too! On my hunt for a solution, i found this post and thought i'd post the solution i've come up with to tackle it.

We can't get Adobe to put the folder anywhere else (i.e. /Library/...), but we can hide the folder by changing the `chflags`.

Type the following into the terminal to **hide** the folder. (It'll still be there, just hidden.)

`chflags hidden ~/Documents/Adobe`

If for whatever reason, you want it visible again, just do this:

`chflags nohidden ~/Documents/Adobe`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is also discussed [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4756345) and [here](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/lr_4_creating_directories_in_inappropriate_locations_documents) (link no longer works) without solutions but where you can track the issue. At the last link you can vote for the issue.

The only solution for getting a clean-looking Documents folder back is marking the Adobe folder as invisible using Windows Explorer.